# AsyncListItemWriter step end detected early

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have wrote an async version of the `ItemWriter` to write my items asynchronously:

```java
public class AsyncListItemWriter<T> implements ItemStreamWriter<T>, InitializingBean {

    private ItemWriter<T> delegate;

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SyncTaskExecutor();

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(delegate, "A delegate ItemWriter must be provided.");
    }

    public void setDelegate(ItemWriter<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        if (delegate instanceof ItemStream) {
            ((ItemStream) delegate).open(executionContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        if (delegate instanceof ItemStream) {
            ((ItemStream) delegate).update(executionContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        if (delegate instanceof ItemStream) {
            ((ItemStream) delegate).close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items)  {
        StepExecution stepExecution = getStepExecution();
        taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            if (stepExecution != null) {
                StepSynchronizationManager.register(stepExecution);
            }
            try {
                delegate.write(items);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stepExecution != null) {
                    StepSynchronizationManager.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        StepContext context = StepSynchronizationManager.getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StepExecution stepExecution = context.getStepExecution();
        return stepExecution;
    }
}
```

The config :

```java
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(64);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(64);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(64);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MultiThreaded-");
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<STModel> writer(){
        return items -> {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Writing...");
            for(STModel c : items) {
                System.out.println("######### Writer : ------> " + c + " inside size : " + c.relation.size() + ", On : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncListItemWriter<STModel> asyncWriter() throws Exception {
        AsyncListItemWriter<STModel> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncListItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(writer());
        asyncItemWriter.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step sampleStep() throws Exception{
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processingStep")
                .<STModel, STModel>chunk(10)
                .reader(itpReader())
                .writer(asyncWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception{
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(sampleStep())
                .build();
    }
```

After reading all the file I receive this logs (the file is read on the main thread) :

> While Same Read ---->STModel(tripId=109138356-1_459178)
> While Same Read ---->STModel(tripId=109138356-1_459178)
> While Same Read ---->null
> Read ---->null, On : main
> 2021-03-16 10:38:48.409  INFO 17042 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [processingStep] executed in 337ms
> 2021-03-16 10:38:48.412  INFO 17042 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 349ms
> Writing...
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=109138355-1_459164) inside size : 2, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=109138355-1_459165) inside size : 1, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=109138355-1_459166) inside size : 1, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=109138355-1_459167) inside size : 1, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=109138355-1_459168) inside size : 2, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507833-1_38959) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507835-1_38960) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507852-1_38961) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507863-1_38962) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-1
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507871-1_38963) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-1
> Writing...
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507882-1_38964) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-2
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507890-1_38965) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-2
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507900-1_38966) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-2
> ######### Writer : ------> STModel(tripId=113507911-1_38967) inside size : 23, On : MultiThreaded-2

---

As you can see, spring batch detect the end of the steap too early, just after the read operations.

How can I tell to spring batch that the end of the step is after all writing tasks has been finished ?

Comment: Async runs in background so as soon as everything is in the background, for Spring Batch the writing has finished. If this isn't what you want, either don't use async, or write a proper async writer that waits for all tasks to finish.

Comment: is there another way to do this async writing by using only spring batch components ?

Comment: Why do you need async writing if you still are going to wait for all threads.

Comment: I want to send a mail after processing all items. The mail now is sent too much early

Comment: Still why do yu need async writing if you are going to wait for it anyway? What does it add?

Comment: writing become concurrent to reading, so it speed up processing !

Comment: and yet you need to wait until everything is written, so there is actually no gain. You would need to wait (countdown latch, futures) for everything to have processed and thus you gain nothing (but complexity) by running this in the background.

Comment: I've passed from 13sec to 2sec when writiing is async ... you seems to be sure that there's no gain ! how ?

Comment: Because when you need to wait it is still blocking and that removes the gain (actually there was no gain as the process still ran in the background). So although your batch job "finished"  quicker, it was not actually done as writing was still going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see, spring batch detect the end of the steap too early,

That's what you should expect, since your writer writes items asynchrnously in the background without waiting for them to finish. As soon as the writer's `write` method returns, the step will continue reading the next chunk of items and might finish if no more items are left to read. This can happen **before** the previous chunk is written in the background by your asynchronous task executor.

> How can I tell to spring batch that the end of the step is after all writing tasks has been finished ?

In your writer, you need `submit` tasks (and not `execute` them), get a handle to their `Future`s and wait for them to finish with `Future.get` (with a timeout if needed).

**EDIT:** Add an example

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends T> items) {
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
    // write items in parallel (note the singleton list passed to the delegate)
    for (T item : items) { 
        Future<?> future = taskExecutor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                delegate.write(Collections.singletonList(item));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        futures.add(future);
    }
    // wait for futures to finish
    futures.forEach(future -> {
        try {
            future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

The only advantage I see here is that items will be written in parallel. This could speed up things for your use case of sending an email for each item. However, I see the following from your comments:

> writing become concurrent to reading, so it speed up processing !

This is not correct, reading the next chunk will still wait for the current write operation to finish. So as mentioned above, you need to wait for the write operation to finish in your writer, otherwise your job could appear to be finished while items are still being written in the background.

If you really want both reads and writes to be done concurrently by multiple threads, you need to use a multi-threaded step:

```
@Bean
public Step sampleStep() throws Exception{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processingStep")
                .<STModel, STModel>chunk(10)
                .reader(itpReader())
                .writer(writer())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
}
```

Another option is to use concurrent steps, as described in this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/2044. I have a PoC that uses a `BlockingQueue` as a staging area [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/blob/master/issues/batch1538/src/main/java/com/example/demo1/ConcurrentStepsSample.java) if you are interested.

Comment: I added an example to the answer.

Comment: `your code in the answer is like AsyncItemWriter`: No, it's different. Your AsyncItemWriter submits a single task that loops over items. The code in the answer will not write items one by one, it writes them in parallel: each thread will write an item. It submits a task per item. This will be faster than writing items in a for loop as you did.

Comment: I just saw your PoC, its grait, that's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Hi, can you have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69347193/parallel-writers-how-to-stop-threads-with-poison-pill-pattern ?Thanks :)