# Parallel writers : How to stop threads with Poison pill pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, java.util.concurrent

Reading in my case must be sequential, and the bottleneck is defined as processing and writing to the database.

I've managed to separate the two process (reading/writing) by using a blocking queue as suggested by [@Mahmoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019386/mahmoud-ben-hassine) [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/blob/main/issues/batch1538/src/main/java/com/example/demo1/ConcurrentStepsSample.java), hence the writing step is able to scale without impacting the reading.

To stop listening on the queue when there is no more items to read, I've introduced the poison-pill pattern. In this case my queue reader become like the following :

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class BlockingQueueItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private final T poisonPill;
    private final int timeoutSeconds;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception {
        T taken = queue.poll(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (poisonPill.equals(taken)) {
            return null;
        }

        return taken;
    }
}
```

To run multiple writing at the same time I've added an executor to step2 like :

```java
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExe-");
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return steps.get("step2")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(new BlockingQueueItemReader<>(queue(), POISON))
                .writer(items -> {
                    for (Person item : items) {
                        System.out.println("item = " + item);
                    }
                })
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(8)
                .build();
    }
```

Now, multiple threads are processing multiple chunks at the same time, that's what I was looking for.

My problem now is with the `BlockingQueueItemReader`. Some readers are blocked at the `poll` line. This happens because of the last read element, it wasn't the `POISON` object, at the same time another thread has found it and returns `null` (so this thread will stops and not the others).

To fix this I've changed the implementation again to this :

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BlockingQueueItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private final T poisonPill;
    private final int timeoutSeconds;
    private boolean exhausted;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception {
        if (exhausted) {
            return null;
        }

        T taken = queue.poll(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        exhausted = poisonPill.equals(taken);
        
        if (exhausted) {
            return null;
        }

        return taken;
    }
}
```

This way all threads exit normally.

My problem is : I'm not happy with this version, the double check on the `exhausted` variable looks ugly !

Is there another way to tell all the involved threads to stop when at least one thread  finds the `POISON` object ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way to tell all the involved threads to stop when at least one thread finds the POISON object ?

I think the "poison pill" idea won't work for this thread synchronization issue (or at least won't be easy to implement cleanly). The timeout-based approach is better in my opinion as it does not require any additional code to inject a poison item in the queue + detect that in the reader + synchronize threads.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The timeout is hard to choose the right value in my case. That's why I'm using the poison-pill. Do I have to synchronize threads in the last implementation ?